# Updating a variable as a parameter in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have a scrolling image script that I'd like to update the scroll speed of on the fly, using a hover function. I've researched and just can't figure out how to get the variable to update inside of the function without calling the function again.  I don't want it to start over, I'd just like the speed to increase as it is running.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () { //on DOM ready
        var defspeed = 1;
        $(".simply-scroll-list").simplyScroll({
            speed: defspeed,
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
$('.fast-forward').hover(function () {
    var defspeed = 5;
});
```

As you can see above, I don't know how to integrate those two blocks of code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increase the speed on the fly in a decent way, because the speed is set only once when you initialize the simpleyScroll plugin.

You could reinitialize the plugin but that could have unwanted side effects. jQuery plugins sometimes add extra html to your DOM and reinitializing it would do that multiple times. Multiple event handlers could get attached to the same nodes and all kinds of stuff could go wrong. I do not know if this is the case with this plugin though. Try it :)

I myself would just add it to the plugin. I don't think it would be hard as the plugin is pretty small.

Comment: Are you sure there are no side effects doing so? Initialising twice sometimes creates extra elements twice. I am not sure in this case though.

Comment: That's a question for @kmmathis. OP?

Comment: No, it isn't creating any extra elements.  It's a usability issue, where simplyscroll jumps back to the beginning when the fast forward element is hovered on, rather than staying at its current position.

Comment: I expected something like that to happen. I'm sure there are other scrollers out there that do what you want.

Comment: I found it **does** add extra html. Pretty crappy plugin. :(

Comment: Its not the plugins fault per se. You should just never reinitialise a plugin twice. The better plugins provide you with public methods (like the jquery ui plugins) to control their inner workings. There's no reason this plugin could not do the same. It was just never built in. :(

Comment: kmmathis, if you have enough time and knowledge you can easily improve the plugin by adding new element to config array onHover that will be function and attach it to the scrolling element. This callback function then can pass plugin instance as a variable and you will get access to it. I am not sure how this plugin is developed so I have no idea how much time and changes it requires.